# Silverlight accessing local computer files

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I have a small application where the user selects a file in `FileDialog` and then I get the path of this file. Simple! 
The problem is that accessing "*://localhost*" it works fine, but accessing via "*://mycomputer/*" I got the following error:

> Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application File operation not
>   permitted. Access to path is denied 'image.jpg'.

I've done all the steps to change the registry, create the certificate, everything ... but nothing solved this problem!

Has anyone experienced this?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "://mycomputer/" try "file://c:/" or "://file/c" as you would from a web browser.